# Travel Approval Requests

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have two date columns, "First Day of Travel" and "Last Day of Travel".  Based on the last day of travel, I want to send a message to all users returning on that last day of travel a email reminder to fill out there Trip Report.  I did go into edit column and try using Column Validation, but it did not work.  Any help in completing this task would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you're suggesting can be achieved by using a workflow.  If you try searching for other posts with the [workflow] tag, it should help with your research

Comment: How do I add another tag to my question?

Comment: There is an 'edit' button under your question - use this

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SharePoint Designer workflow to achieve it.

Design it like the image below, you can customize the email body as your requirement:
[image]

For the Start Options, you can set:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!